# I can't delete data multiple in mysql from python

Tags: python, mysql

**I made input 2 value row and num when input data so program throw Rollback not work if-else and thank for help**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import mysql.connector
conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="",user="",passwd="",db="")
cursor = conn.cursor()
try:
        row = raw_input("InputNameRow : ")
        num = int(input("InputNumber 1-10 : "))
        if num <= 10:
                sql1 = "SELECT * FROM dt WHERE '%s' = '%d' " %(row,num)
                cursor.execute(sql1)
                data = cursor.fetchall()
                print(data[0])
                sqlde = "DELETE FROM dt WHERE '%s' = '%d' " %(row,num)
                cursor.execute(sqlde, (num))
                print "DELETE SUCESS"
                conn.commit()
        else:
                print "Data Empty"
except:
        conn.rollback()
        print "Input Error"

conn.close()
```

Comment: what are 3 values in sql1 = "SELECT * FROM dt WHERE '%s' = '%d' " %(row,row,num) ? I guess there should be only 2 values..

Comment: why you are passing parameter in cursor.execute(sqlde, (row,num)) ?

Comment: **WARNING**: Use the prepared statements feature present in the Python database layer to [properly escape your values](http://bobby-tables.com/python.html) and avoid [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Don't use the standard string methods for this, you'll create huge holes.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
cursor.execute(sqlde)
```

instead of

```
cursor.execute(sqlde, (num))
```